# Pandas apply aggregate difference

Tags: python, pandas

I am confused about the difference of pandas aggregate and apply. And I do not think this question is answer in other questions, to the best of my knowledge.
All the following four work. (test is a categorical variables with values equal to 0 or 1)

```
data.groupby('source').apply(lambda x: len(x['test'][data['test']==0]))
data.groupby('source').apply(lambda x: len(x['test'][x['test']==0]))
data.groupby('source')['test'].apply(lambda x: len(x[x==0]))
data.groupby('source')['test'].agg(lambda x: len(x[x==0]))
```

The result is

```
source
Ads       95245
Direct    47691
SEO       94157
Name: test, dtype: int64
```

But this will give me an `KeyError: 'test'`.

```
data.groupby('source').agg(lambda x: len(x['test'][x['test']==0]))
```

Why I can not put `['test']` after `x` when using `agg`, but can do this when using `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

if you do `data.groupby('source').agg(lambda x: print(type(x))`, you will notice that they are `'pandas.core.series.Series'`, when using `agg`, it treat with individual series